# Spring JPA, JSON, Security Exception No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I apologize that this is a common question - but I am a bit lost trying to correct my code.  I have a JPA/JSON/Spring Security application that is failing to start with the exception: "No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined".  I have attached my web.xml and security-context xml below.  Fromwhat I can work out the later may not being loaded correctly?  Any help appreciated.  I have been through other questions with no luck

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Application</display-name>


    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:root-context.xml
            classpath:security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/api/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

security-context.xml  (/WEB-INF/spring/api/security-context.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Rest authentication entry point configuration -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="restServicesEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManagerForRest">
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" />
        <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="myAuthenticationAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <!-- Entry point for REST service. -->
    <beans:bean id="restServicesEntryPoint" class="foo.bar.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint1" />

    <!-- Custom User details service which is provide the user data -->
    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="foo.bar.CustomUserDetailsService" />

    <!-- Connect the custom authentication success handler -->
    <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="foo.bar.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <!-- Using Authentication Access Denied handler -->
    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationAccessDeniedHandler" class="foo.bar.RestAuthenticationAccessDeniedHandler" />

    <!-- Authentication manager -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManagerForRest">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- Enable the annotations for defining the secure role -->
    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

</beans:beans>
```

SpringSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml" })
@ComponentScan("foo.bar.security")
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    public SpringSecurityConfig() {

        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `security-context.xml (/WEBINF/spring/api/security-context.xml)` located ? it should be in `security-context.xml (/WEB-INF/spring/api/security-context.xml)` with dash.

Comment: `/WEBINF/spring/api/security-context.xml` isn't `class path:security-context.xml`. `WEB-INF` isn't part of the class path...

Comment: as @M.Deinum said, put your security-context.xml in your WEB-INF folder. WEB-INF (with dash) then change contextConfigLocation param not to scan in your classpath but reference it directly like this:  `<param-value>
/WEB-INF/spring/api/security-context.xml
        </param-value>`

Comment: Actually that is a typo - sorry should be WEB-INF.   Will try direct reference.

Comment: I have tried this now and I get the same Exception.  security is in the path per your example and web.xml modified.

Comment: update your question with latest code

Comment: ok - I have now added a Class as above and all seems to work - not sure why the class loads security-context.xml and web.xml does not seem to?